Unhandled Runtime Error Error: Expected a suspended thenable. This is a bug in React. Please file an issue
I am implementing next-intel to provide translations for French and Arabic audiences, currently I have come to the theme provider and locale selector configuration which worked great without any issues. When I am working on a dynamic page [pid] on nextjs and especially. using Firebase to fetch data and create a page on the server, the problem occurs:
Unhandled execution error Error: A suspended thenable was expected. This is a bug in React. Please report an issue.
I cleaned my build .next folder and reloaded node_modules, without result, I even created a new project and deleted all files concerning translations without result.

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/28659 . Note that that error message is slightly differently worded, so probably a different cause.

Try changing the React version.

If your page is async server component, and I believe it is since you said it fetches data from Firebase, then you can't use useTranslations hook. You have to use getTranslations function and await it.
Server Component:
const t = useTranslations('HomePage');
Async Server Component:
const t = await getTranslations('HomePage');
Please check the next-intl docs for more details: https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/environments/server-client-components#async-components

RESOLVED!
The problem occurs when using a client hook like useTranslations, in my case on the server, so I have two options to solve the problem:
1- "use client" directive to mention the file as a client component
2- Revoke the use Translations hook from the page, which is a server component, and move it to the children which are client components.
There you go, hope this helps someone who has come across this.
OPTION 1:
before:
  import { useTranslations } from "next-intl";
import HorizontalMenuWithSearch from "../../components/HorizontalMenuWithSearch";
export  default async function Page() {
 
  const t = useTranslations("common");
  return (
    <>
     <HorizontalMenuWithSearch/>
    </>
  );
}

after:
'use client';

  import { useTranslations } from "next-intl";
import HorizontalMenuWithSearch from "../../components/HorizontalMenuWithSearch";
export  default async function Page() {
 
  const t = useTranslations("common");
  return (
    <>
     <HorizontalMenuWithSearch/>
    </>
  );
}

=================================================================
OPTION 2:
before:
  import { useTranslations } from "next-intl";
import HorizontalMenuWithSearch from "../../components/HorizontalMenuWithSearch";
export  default async function Page() {
 
  const t = useTranslations("common");
  return (
    <>
     <HorizontalMenuWithSearch/>
    </>
  );
}

after:
'use client';

 // import { useTranslations } from "next-intl"; to be removed
import HorizontalMenuWithSearch from "../../components/HorizontalMenuWithSearch";
export  default async function Page() {
 
 // const t = useTranslations("common"); romove this
  return (
    <>
     <HorizontalMenuWithSearch/>
    </>
  );
}


In my case, reverting the pnpm-lock.yaml fixed the issue.
